# Can someone explain how is result in this function -2 ? Python

Tags: python, function

Can someone explain to me how is output -2 and why? If it is possible to write the procedure how it came to be

```
def f(a):
  if a > 10:
    return f(a-1) - f(a-3)
  else:
    return 1

b = 13
c = f(b)
print(c)
```

Comment: Just think what the result would be for 10, for 11, then for 12 using the result for 11 and finally for 13. The program basically does this in reverse order.

Comment: Please exhibit some debugging effort. What happens if you add `print(a)` just before `return f(a-1) - f(a-3)`?

Comment: @tripleee

output:
13
12
11
-2
But all good, i got answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating series of recurences, at the end output is just 1-1-1-1 = -2

First f(13) = f(12) - 1 = f(11) - 1 - 1 = 1 - 1 - 1 - 1

Comment: Thank you!

So point there is:

f(13) = f(12) - 1 = ... (then repeating again whole function of f(12)... so f(12) = f(11) -1 ( and we add - 1 where we calculate f(12) - 1,  am i right?

Comment: The function is calling itself from inside, but with other parameters, until all the values inside f() are not greater than 10. What you wrote is probably right

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand what the function does.
It will nest itself until the value of "a" is less than 10 and then return 1.
Expect for the first loop which will always return f(a-1) - f(a-3).
So basically you have (1-1) - (1-3) = 0 - 2 = -2

Comment: Less than 11 (or not greater than 10)

Comment: oh yeah, mb. But the logic is pretty much the same anyways.